# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment when running .\import.io

Tags: java, web-scraping, ubuntu-12.04, import.io

I have download import.io as per the link,
https://import.io/download/linux. As it says, I have extracted and get inside the folder `import.io` in terminal. But when I tried running `./import.io`, I am getting this error(Given below). Kindly advice me to resolve this issue. I appreciate your help.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

**Java version**
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

**Error**

```
Starting application...
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xdedda7e4, pid=12312, tid=4149622464
#
# JRE version: 7.0_09-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.5-b02 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libdbus-1.so.3+0x277e4]
[error occurred during error reporting (printing problematic frame), id 0xb]
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/user/import.io/hs_err_pid12312.log
# [ timer expired, abort... ]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**This is the log**

```
!SESSION 2014-04-25 14:25:17.199 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_09
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-04-25 14:25:17.712
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1634)
    at com.importio.builder.bootstrap.ui.SwtUI.<init>(SwtUI.java:74)
    at com.importio.builder.bootstrap.ui.SwtUI.run(SwtUI.java:41)
    at com.importio.builder.bootstrap.BootstrapApplication.start(BootstrapApplication.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

**Edit**

[Here](http://pastebin.com/SiAH94GM) is my Error when I tried running script as suggested by Anone Mosh in Comments section. Please see the log also.

**Log**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xded37b12, pid=5628, tid=3739306816
#
# JRE version: 7.0_09-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.5-b02 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libdbus-1.so.3+0x29b12]
```

Comment: did you try `ulimit -c unlimited` on terminal?? what does *hs_err_pid12312.log* say??

Comment: I didn't try that. I will do that and let you know. Please see, I have added the log it now.

Comment: Noob, it was my mistake while posting the question. I have been using `./import.io` . I will edit it in my question.

Comment: You running this from your local system, or via an SSH session? An error before launching like this indicates that you don't have an X server available.

Comment: Hi Petesh, I am using SSH. But I am using SSH command as 'ssh user@10.3.3.2 -Y'

Comment: Do other simple X applications work e.g. gedit?

Comment: Try running it locally, not over the network.

Comment: Ok, I will try and let you know.

Comment: Still its not working. Please see my Error and Log in Edit section of my question.

Comment: @Petesh I can open gedit using SSH.

Answer (score 5):

Java is having problems calling dbus to detect any HTTP proxies you may have setup. Do you have any proxies? If not you can turn this detection off by adding the following line to the following file:

`<where you extracted the application to>/import.io/import.io.ini`

This is the line you need to add to the file:

`-Dupdate.useSystemProxy=false`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the errors is because you are using linux version that is 64bits. Follow the instruction through and you wont experience any error. http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/254346-linux-installation-notes.

Answer (score 1):

This solution work for me:
Edit the file /eclipse/eclipse.ini.
Insert the line:
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=m